# Math image OCR (how to)

Tags: javascript, image, ocr

So it's all about this image!
Is there a good OCR software to OCR it?!

http://img806.imageshack.us/i/secure.jpg/

I tried it with some free OCR-s and I have 50% results--sometimes it manages to OCR a part, sometimes it OCRs the whole picture!

BTW could it be done over javascript somehow?!

Comment: So you want do build a Captcha cracker?... JavaScript is definitely not going to be the right language for this under any circumstance. But it looks easy enough to get *somewhat* good results with any normal OCR software, I guess

Comment: Yes something like that.Im beginer a programing!First i need to build the "captcha cracker" or find some and then try to use it with another program.Could you advise what OCR could i use?!

Answer (score 2):

Actually, someone already implemented a greasemonkey script to solve an OCR.
It's written in Javascript, and is very specific (built to solve only one site's captcha).

Here's an article about it:

http://ejohn.org/blog/ocr-and-neural-nets-in-javascript/

And here's the source (cached version):

[http://userscripts.org/scripts/review/38736](https://web.archive.org/web/20130118112444/http://userscripts.org/scripts/review/38736)

Comment: A cached version of the script is available here:
https://web.archive.org/web/20130118112444/http://userscripts.org/scripts/review/38736